# Get the details of Listeners on Azure Relay

Tags: azure-servicebusrelay, azure-relay

I am using Azure ServiceBus Relay and although I am able to fetch the count of the current listeners, I want to know the details of those listeners as well. For example, their id or address. An attribute that I can use to access or target that particular listener. 
As of now I am sending a GET request to :

```
https://{our relay}.servicebus.windows.net/
```

with a SAS token as header and returned object is:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">Publicly Listed Services</title>
    <subtitle type="text">This is the list of publicly-listed services currently available.</subtitle>
    <id>uuid:85ad7592-cecf-4f31-bef2-4bb7f5cea444;id=2185</id>
    <updated>2019-12-17T10:27:55Z</updated>
    <generator>Service Bus 1.1</generator>
</feed>
```